# relocation error on running python script from php

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to run my python script from php. I get the following error

```
python: relocation error: python: symbol SSL_load_error_strings, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

I'm using import socket in python script which is causing the error.

Any help with would be much appreciated.

php_code -

```
shell_exec('python C:/xampp/htdocs/webInterface/php_ex/pyth_1.py  aa  2>&1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Xampp comes with it's own version of the common libraries.

When you run Python from PHP, the environment variables are set to find Xampp libs, and their versions might differ from what Python is expecting.

On unix, to see what is different run from PHP:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/env');
```

Then compare the output of the same command from a terminal window.

For me, unsetting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was all I needed to get Python working:

```
shell_exec("LD_LIBRARY_PATH='' python myscript.py");
```